# Is it possible learning Statistical mechanics from a chemistry/biochem perspective?

Tags: statistical-mechanics, resource-recommendations, education

Basically I have a major in biochem and want to learn some stats mech, but i dont really care about the physics. Im more interested in learning the subject with more of a chemical/biochemical focus. Is there any resources like videos/lectrue notes/books for my purpose?

Comment: The subject chemists call "physical chemistry" is essentially the same discipline that physicists call "thermal physics" or "thermodynamics and statistical mechanics", albeit the too groups approach it from different perspective. And both treat it differently that most engineers.